# Why is `Object.length === 1` in JavaScript as part of browsers?

Tags: javascript

I'm troubleshooting something in Angular that ends up checking `Object.length`. The result is 1. The string representation of it does not show any arguments. I get that the first argument is used.

```
var obj = new Object({ a : 27 });
```

[`Object`'s constructor function lists the argument as optional.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

```js
document.write(Object.length);
```

So why/how is it counted?

Comment: It's mandated by the spec: http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3

Comment: I don't think the string representation (I assume you mean `Object.toString()` so some equivalent) of native functions can be counted on to reflect the number of parameter it takes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The length of a function is the number of declared arguments, **excluding any rest parameter**.

From the MDN:

> length is a property of a function object, and indicates how many
>   arguments the function expects, i.e. the number of formal parameters.
>   This number does not include the rest parameter.

[There's exactly one for the `Object` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), the optional wrapped value.

Moreover, in the specific case of the Object function, [the ES spec explicitly mandates it should have a length of 1](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3):

> Besides the internal properties and the length property (whose value is 1)

(it seems to do so for all functions taking a rest parameter, like `Array` or `fromCharCode`)

Note that the ([implementation dependent](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.2)) string representation of native functions in browsers doesn't necessarily show the formal arguments.