# length property in built-in Object, Number

Tags: javascript

Why does the built-in Object, `Number`, have a `length` property?

```js
var n = Number;
n;
```

```json
EPSILON: 2.220446049250313e-16
MAX_SAFE_INTEGER: 9007199254740991
MAX_VALUE: 1.7976931348623157e+308
MIN_SAFE_INTEGER: -9007199254740991
MIN_VALUE: 5e-324
NEGATIVE_INFINITY: -Infinity
NaN: NaN
POSITIVE_INFINITY: Infinity
isFinite: ƒ isFinite()
isInteger: ƒ isInteger()
isNaN: ƒ isNaN()
isSafeInteger: ƒ isSafeInteger()
length: 1 // For what??
```

Comment: Number is a function, the `length` property on a function represents the number of arguments that is expected to be passed to it.

Comment: @NickParsons aha Thanks. But the `var n = Number` didn't passed any parameter

Comment: `Number` _can be_ passed one argument (see the [constructor docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number) for it). The `length` isn't what you have passed to it, it is the number of arguments that it can be passed (that it will use).

Comment: @NickParsons Oh I'll read that. Thanks!

Comment: The explanation here applies to your case also: [Why is \`Object.length === 1\` in JavaScript as part of browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29301822)

Comment: @NickParsons OMG, What a really kind developer! Really really thanks very much.